DSTX package did not generate any output and fails the job step
I have a bunch of DSTX packages that are scheduled to run everyday.
But a couple of them started seemingly randomly to fail, as a workaround I just set retries but sometimes doesn't help. They succeed less than 1 out of 10 attempts.
Message
Executed as user: WORKGROUP\sqlsrvvwarehouse. The step did not generate any output.  The return value was unknown.  The process exit code was -1073741819.

I can't see anything useful in the logs, on some forum I found something regarding increasing the heap size, I increased it but doesn't make any difference.
I compared similar packages that work fine and I can't see any difference.
Any idea about where to look for?
The package is a basic workflow that truncates a table and then import an excel file into the table.
The excel tables are not that big either.

This error code often indicates an unhandled exception or an issue with memory allocation during package execution.

Ensure that your connection managers (especially the ones related to Oracle and SQL Server) are correctly configured.
Verify that the package configurations (if any) are set up correctly.
Check whether the packages run successfully when executed manually
If you haven't already, try running the package in debug mode from Visual Studio.
which settings did you adjust in heap size? For SSIS, you need to adjust the memory allocated to the SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) or the SQL Server Integration Services service.
chek if your server has limited memory
Double-check the Excel source connection. Sometimes issues arise from incorrect column mappings or data types.
Consider breaking down the package into smaller tasks (e.g., separate truncation and import steps) to pinpoint where the failure occurs.
Verify that the version of SQL Server you're using (including SSIS) is fully supported and up to date
If you're using SQL Server 2019, there was a known issue related to intermittent package failures
As a best practice, maintain version control for your SSIS packages. If you've made recent changes, consider rolling back to a known working version to see if the issue persists

